# Bound checkbox does not initialize to "checked" when v-model value is truthy (e.g. non-empty string)

Tags: vue.js

My checkbox is bound to a model value that is a truthy value ("test"), yet the checkbox initializes to "unchecked".

https://jsbin.com/hixarug/edit?html,js,console,output

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox">checkbox
</div>
```

```
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checkbox: "test"
  }
})
```

Comment: but why are you using a string value instead of boolean one?

Comment: This works fine in vue `2.2.0` up. But as @BoussadjraBrahim said, you should set it to boolean

Comment: if you don't need that `test` value later, you could use this  `checkbox:"test"?true:false`

Comment: My use-case is much more involved than I have, intentionally, included.

Comment: Ah, thank you @ljubadr, you are correct about the version. I glanced over the fact that jsbin inserted an older version. The jsbin is updated, and it works. Now to figure out what to do with this question.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: It said I can't for 2 days. If one of you wants to post, I'll accept, otherwise, I will when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, I assumed that the latest version of Vue available in jsbin (2.0.3) was the latest version of Vue. It works as of 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `"test"` as `true` and (I assume) `""` as `false`, you can do it like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" true-value="test" false-value="" v-model="checkbox">
```

[Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1)